# Angular material datepicker does't arrange items on a single row

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, datepicker

In my web application I'm using an angular material datepicker.
The issue is that it does not show all the elements in a row.
This is my view:

[Datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7gEq.png)

To avoid that my customized css has an impact on the view I removed every customized style.

This way, my html is very simple. I simply copied and pasted the angular material example from angular official portal (basic datepicker item):

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

But according to the angular material exaple on-line the image should be something like this:
[Basi datepicker from angular material online help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS2r3.png)

In what am I wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `matSuffix` instead of `matIconSuffix` in your `mat-datepicker-toggle`.

Edit following @TotallyNewb's comment.

Angular version <= v14: matSuffix

Angular version >= v15: matIconSuffix

Comment: As a side-note - this is one of many changes between major versions (14 vs 15). So make sure you're reading docs for the correct version, as the for stuff tends to change.